# Pagination with Jquery or Django?

Tags: jquery, django, pagination

Can't decide which pagination solution to use and i need some advice!

I'm using jquery load() to get different list of objects from my django views. I'm rendering the lists in a child html and loading it into a div on my main page. I've contructed the site like this. It's doesn't change sites when clicking different links but loads results/child htmls in divs or dialogs.

So the standard django pagination does not work. I'd have to rebuild the previus/next links somehow to load the results into the same div.

Maybe it's easier to just do the pagination with a Jquery (plugin?) instead? I'm already using a tablesorter plugin to sort the lists and i dont think it would work with djangos pagination anyway (it would probably just work on one page at the time and not sort the whole list).

Im asking for some general ideas and advice on this. How would you do the pagination?

Answer (score 1):

You want either Django pagination or a Javascript solution--but not both.

If you table-sorting in JS, your users probably expect that to sort the entire table--not just the rows that you get for this page of Django. Probably you want to not use Django pagination at all and have this all done in JS. If you're using jQuery tablesort, there already is a pagination plugin for it.

Comment: Ok. Thats what i was thinking also. But then again, maybe doing the pagination on the frond-end is going make it load slow in the future if there is a lot of objects. I guess i could build some kind of sorting function with Django also.. It might be worth it in the long run (?). Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: @user3199840 I'm in this case, I confused to consider between Pagination on django or JS, in django, my view response a json file contain all posts and I want to display10 post/page, so any way to test speed to compare them if I use pagination on django or JS ?